# Execution on multiple package

Tags: java, package

I'm currently working on a java project, and I have to make to script files to compile and run it.

Here is the structure of the project (it's one of the requirement, I can't change it):

```
.  
+-- logger/
|  +-- src/
|  |   +-- logger/
|  |       +-- (*.java)
|  +-- bin/
+-- restaurant/
|  +-- src/
|  |   +-- restaurant/
|  |       +-- (*.java)
|  +-- bin/
+-- compile.sh
+-- test.sh
```

My file that I use to compile is this one :

```
rm -r logger/bin  
mkdir logger/bin 
javac -d logger/bin $(find logger/src -name *.java) 

rm -r restaurant/bin 
mkdir restaurant/bin 
javac -classpath logger/bin -d restaurant/bin $(find restaurant/src -name *.java)
```

This file is actually working, it compiles the two packages at the right places (bin repertories).

My main class is in the class called "Caisse.java" :

```
package restaurant.src.restaurant; 
public class Caisse { public static void main(String[] args) { 
    [...] 
}
```

So now that my whole code is compiled I want to run it with this script :

```
java -classpath logger/bin:banking/bin restaurant.src.restaurant.Caisse
```

But I have this error :

> Error: Could not find or load main class restaurant.src.restaurant.Caisse

Thanks in advance for your help, I hope that I've been specific enough.

Comment: The class files generated need to be in their original package structure.

Comment: The packages at the root of my project "logger" and "restaurant" are not their original packages ?

Comment: If you base directory is `restaurant/bin`, you have to have a `restaurant/bin/restaurant/src/restaurant/Caisse.class` file. The package directories need to be under the base directory.  Keeping track of these is tedious as you get larger projects which is why I use maven and an IDE.

Comment: So you mean that I need to move my package `restaurant/src`under the repository `restaurant/bin` ? 
(Sorry if I don't understand very well)

Comment: @CorentinF. no. You need to check if you indeed have a file restaurant/bin/restaurant/src/restaurant/Caisse.class. And you should learn to use standard, much better build tools such as gradle or Maven.

Comment: I do have this file.
I'm using an IDE, but one of the requirements for this project is to have those scripts.

Comment: Then my guess is that you're executing your command from the wrong directory.

Comment: I'm running it from the same directory from which I run compile.sh.

Comment: @JBNizet Should I run it from another directory ? To me it's the right one